# Inkscape TexText ! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble

Tags: pdftex, inkscape

I am trying to run this code in inkscape with textext:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\textbf{a.}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
    \draw
       (0,3) to [V,l_=$5 + 20\cos(100\pi t)+10\cos(200\pi t)$] (0,0)
      to [short,i_=$i_s$] (1,0)
      to [R, l_=$\pi\si{\Omega}$] (3,0)
      to [C, l_=$1000\pi\si{\micro\farad}$] (3,3)
      to [L, l_=$\pi\si{\milli\henry}$] (0,3);
  \end{circuitikz}
  \begin{align*}
      f = \frac{100\pi}{2\pi}=50\si{\hertz}
  \end{align*}
\end{figure}
\textbf{b.}
\begin{align*}
      \text{THD}=\frac{\sqrt{\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}h_n^2}}{h_1}=\frac{\sqrt{h_2^2}}{h_1}=\frac{10}{20}=0.5=50\%
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The code works fine on overleaf but when I put in into inkscape I am getting this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
```

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./tmp.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-11>
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
No file tmp.aux.
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)

! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9     \documentclass
                      [preview]{standalone}
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9     \documentclass
                      [preview]{standalone}
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on tmp.log.
```

I tried deleting documentclass line or usepackage lines or both there are still errors.

Comment: tmp.tex has `\documentclass` on line 9, so is not the code you are showing

Comment: @DavidCarlisle where is tmp.tex, I am opening inkscape -> extensions -> text -> tex text and putting my code there

Comment: I don't know I was just reading the log you posted. I guess inkscape is just expecting a tex fragment and wraps it in a new documentclass so you end up with two, but I haven't used that feature

Comment: When I delete the documentclass line the error is still occuring

Comment: `tex text` is for small text fragments, like `$\alpha$` etc. It will automatically warp a class, some default package and a document environment around the code fragment you give it, which will cause a problem of the code fragment itself contains these things as well. If you want to typeset a complete document, better do this outside of inkscape and then include the result as pdf or svg in your inkscape drawing.